# Trouble reading MARC data using MARCReader() and pymarc

Tags: python, ascii, marc

So I am trying to teach myself python and pymarc for a school project I am working on.  I have a sample marc file and I am trying to read it using this simple code:

```
from pymarc import *

reader = MARCReader(open('dump.mrc', 'rb'), to_unicode=True)

for record in reader:
    print(record)
```

The for loop is to just print out each record to make sure I am getting the correct data.  The only thing is I am getting this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've looked online but could not find an answer to my problem.  What does this error mean and how can I go about fixing it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the python environment to support UTF-8 and get record as a dictionary.

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

from pymarc import *

reader = MARCReader(open('dump.mrc', 'rb'), to_unicode=True, force_utf8=True)
for record in reader:
    print record.as_dict()
```

Note:

1. If you still get the unicode exception, you can set to_unicode=False and skip force_utf8=True.
2. Also please check if your dump.mrc file is encoded to UTF-8 or not. Try: 
   $ chardet dump.mrc